# View retention in Google Play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

It was supposed to be in "User acquisition" tab, but the tab is not there in the new version of the console.
I want to view the basic retention metrics - what % of the users came back the next day. In percentages. Is it possible somewhere from the dashboard or from the statistics tab?